# Communicating between Ti CC2530 and Digi ConnectPortX4

Tags: zigbee, xbee

I want to use a Digi ConnectPortX4 as a coordinator and Texus instrument CC2530 chip as a end device can anyone please help about communicating this two device.

Answer (score 3):

The Digi ConnectPort X4 and the TI CC2530 can speak to one another.  First, make certain the Digi ConnectPort X4 is running the latest firmware and its XBee ZB modules has been updated to the latest version.

This will only work if the TI CC2530 is running a ZigBee PRO 2007 stack.

Navigate to the "XBee Networks" page of the ConnectPort X4's web user interface.  Click on the Coordinator (Address "[0000]!"), this will load the ZigBee Coordinator settings.  Next, click on "Advanced Settings" and scroll all the way down to find the "Stack Profile" parameter.  Set "Stack Profile" to 2 and click "Apply".  This set the ConnectPort X4 up for ZigBee PRO 2007 mode rather than private ZigBee profile mode.